# InvalidOperationException : Invalid operation. The connection is closed. in Asp.Net MVC while trying to serialize the class object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
[InvalidOperationException: Invalid operation. The connection is closed.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.GetOpenConnection() +2417814
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.get_ServerVersion() +9
```

I am getting this error while i am serialize my object.

```
 public string SerializeObj(TemplateData obj)
    {
        string data = null;
        try
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            ** data = js.Serialize(obj); [This is what i am finding issue is][1]**
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException iopException)
        {
            string exception = iopException.Data.ToString();
            return exception;
        }
        return data;
```

please note : I am not using database connection when i am serialize my object.

Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this issue ?

When i am serializing my object it's taking my class named TemplateData.

```
  public List<TemplateData> List(string myKey)
    {
        TemplateBusinessLogic businessLogic = new TemplateBusinessLogic();
        TemplateData templateData = new TemplateData();
        templateData.key = myKey;
            string postKey = businessLogic.SerializeObj(templateData);
        string listUrl = MandrillAutomation.Helper.Config.ConfigManager.ConstantsConfig.GetValue("listUrl");
        string requestContent = HttpRequestUrl(listUrl, "POST", postKey);
        List<TemplateData> listContent = businessLogic.DeserializeObj<List<TemplateData>>(requestContent); // DESERIALIZE OBJECT

        for (int i = 0; i <= listContent.Count-1; i++)
        {
            FileHelper fileHelp = new FileHelper();
            fileHelp.SaveTemplate(listContent[i].name, listContent[i].code);
        }
        //SaveTemplate(listContent);  //Save Templates into desire format

        log.Info(listContent.Count + " Templates avilable" );
        log.Info("[  ");
        log.Info("Templates :" + GetTemplateName(listContent));
        log.Info("  ]");
        foreach (var content in listContent)
        {
            log.Info("Name of Template : " + content.name + " || Slug of Template : " + content.slug + " || in Account : " + myKey);
        }
        return listContent;
    }
```

And i have class TemplateData as below :

```
 public class TemplateData :DbContext
{
    public string key {get; set;}
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public string fromEmail { get; set; }
    public string fromName { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string publish { get; set; }
    public string[] labels { get; set; }
    public string created_at{ get; set; }
    public string updated_at { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the code that calls this method and how are you passing the value  of `obj`?

Comment: It have type of my TemplateData. Wait i am add it into my question

Comment: I copied your model and the `SerializeObj()` method to a new project, ran it and there was no error. There must be something else in code you have not shown us that's causing the issue.

Comment: Hey @ Stephen Muecke  Thanks for Help.
I am getting my mistake. I extend DbContext class with my TemplateData Class.
I am remove it from there So there was no any error.

Thanks

Comment: You should either delete the question, or add your own answer and accept it to close this out :)

Comment: Ya Sure ...
I am adding my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am just removing `DbContext` from my `TemplateData` class.
And there is no error now. :)